# How to create 2x2 bar plot - with side by side pairwise bar in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following data:

```
  Method    Metric        E0        E1        E2        E4
1     M1 Precision 0.9661017 0.9622642 1.0000000 0.9655172
2     M2 Precision 0.5330000 0.5350000 0.3780000 0.2140000
3     M1    Recall 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
4     M2    Recall 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.6670000
```

What I want to do is to create the above data into the following plot:

[image]

In this sketch the height of the bar doesn't reflect the data above, surely.

What's the way to do it? 
Prefferably without using external libraries like ggplot or lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

Import:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Method  Metric  E0  E1  E2  E4
M1  Precision   0.9661017   0.9622642   1   0.9655172
M2  Precision   0.533   0.535   0.378   0.214
M1  Recall  0.9736842   0.9736842   0.9473684   0.9473684
M2  Recall  1   1   1   0.667",header=TRUE)
```

Define a layout and some colours:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,5,3,4,5),nrow=2,byrow = TRUE))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    5
#[2,]    3    4    5
barcols <- c("red","blue")
```

Generate some plots:

```
sapply(3:6, 
  function(x) {
    bp <- barplot(matrix(dat[,x],nrow=2,byrow=TRUE),beside=TRUE,col=barcols)
    title(main=names(dat[x]))
    axis(1,at=colMeans(bp),c("M1","M2"),lwd=0,lwd.tick=1)
    abline(h=0)
  }
)
```

Add a legend:

```
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
legend(0,0.6,c("Precision","Recall"),fill=barcols,cex=1.5)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a million. Do you mind look at the follow-up questions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21274527/67405

Answer (score 4):

I realize you are trying to avoid external libraries, but `ggplot` was designed to make this easy.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

gg <- melt(df,id=1:2)
ggplot(gg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Method, y=value, fill=Metric), stat="identity",
           position="dodge")+facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]